# ChromeCast: The method getActionProvider(MenuItem) is undefined for the type MenuItemCompat

Tags: android, chromecast

Trying to add ChromeCast support form may app and getting the following error:

> The method getActionProvider(MenuItem) is undefined for the type MenuItemCompat

My Code:

**Menu XML**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  ...

  <item android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
    android:title="Chromecast"
    android:orderInCategory="500"
android:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
    android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton"
    android:showAsAction="never" />

 </menu>
```

**Activity:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.ContentProviderClient;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter.RouteInfo;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.cast.ApplicationMetadata;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.Cast;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.Cast.MessageReceivedCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.CastDevice;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.CastMediaControlIntent;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;


public class MyApp extends FragmentActivity {
 ...

@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    ...


    MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item);
    MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider = (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat
            .getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem);
    // Set the MediaRouteActionProvider selector for device discovery.
    mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(mMediaRouteSelector);


 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 1):

Import android.view.Menu and MenuItem, not the compat one:

```
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

Your menu xml has a couple of things that you night want to update:

- Remove the actionViewClass
- cast icon should always be visible, so make it: showAsAction="always"

A sample xml could be:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
    android:title="@string/media_route_menu_title"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Try these and see if that helps.

Comment: My imports were already as you suggested.  I've fixed the xml code, but that has no impact on this issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  It was able to get me on the right track.  See accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the source of this issue was that I was using an outdated **android-support-v4.jar** library in my project.  I imported the latest file and the error was resolved.